# Nested groups with aggregation framework

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, aggregation-framework

In my collection I have an amount of documents that each contains 4 types of categories.

- `group`
- `mainCategory`
- `subCategory`
- `subSubCategory`

I'm looking for a way to `$group` this by `group` and inside `group` there should be an array of `mainCategory`, in `mainCategory` there should be an array of `subCategory` and in the `subCategory` there should be an array of the `subSubCategory`.  The result should only contain the values/names of the categories.

Expected result:

```
const result = [
            {
              "group": "Teknik",
              "mainCategory": [
                {
                  "name": "Gaming",
                  "subCategory": [
                    {
                      "name": "Playstation",
                      "subSubCategory": [
                        {"name": "Games"},
                        {"name": "Accessories"},
                        {"name": "Console"}
                      ]
                    },
                    {
                      "name": "Xbox",
                      "subSubCategory": [
                        {"name": "Games"},
                        {"name": "Accessories"},
                        {"name": "Console"}
                      ]
                    }
                  ]
                }, {
                  "name": "Audio",
                  "subCategory": [
                    {
                      "name": "Headphones",
                      "subSubCategory": [
                        {"name": "Wireless"},
                        {"name": "Non Wireless"},
    
                      ]
                    },
                    {
                      "name": "Speakers",
                      "subSubCategory": [
                        {"name": ""},
                      ]
                    }
                  ]
                },
    
              ]
            }
]
```

I think the problem is that I need to `$push` each and every category in the parent one and create new `$groups`? But when adding more `$group`s it's only the last one that is "saved". The other ones seems to not be "saved". Or is something else that im doing wrong?

Sample data and working code based on prev. test data.

https://mongoplayground.net/p/C0-L-rGPfwy

Product structure in the collection

```
productName :"Horizon Zero Dawn"
group:"Teknik"
mainCategory: "Gaming"
subCategory:"Playstation"
subSubCategory: "Games"
```

My aggregation

```
const categories = await Product.aggregate([
        {$match: {group: 'Teknik'}},
        {
          $group: {
            _id: {
              group: '$group',
              mainCategory: '$mainCategory',
              subCategory: '$subCategory',
              subSubCategory: '$subSubCategory',
            }
          },
        },
        {
          $group: {
            _id: "$_id.group",
            mainCategory: {
              $push:
                {
                  name: "$_id.mainCategory",
                  subCategory: {
                    name: "$_id.subCategory",
                    subSubCategory: {
                      name: "$_id.subSubCategory"
                    }
                  }
                }
            },
          }
        },
      ]);
```

With this i get 1 object for each subSubcategory, but i would like them in the same object.

```
"_id": "Teknik",
    "mainCategory": [
    {
            "name": "Gaming",
            "subCategory": {
                "name": "Xbox",
                "subSubCategory": {
                    "name": "Games"
                }
            }
        },
    {
            "name": "Spel & Gaming",
            "subCategory": {
                "name": "Xbox",
                "subSubCategory": {
                    "name": "Accessories"
                }
            }
        },
]
```

Comment: @turivishal It's in the top of the post the const result = [...] But clarified it now.

Comment: There is around 40 000 documents so i added some sample data in a link above. https://mongoplayground.net/p/QjjPTuQWspt .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The process is to prepare from end level of array:

> 1. **subSubCategory** *(group by below 3 level of fields)*
>
> > 2. **subCategory** *(group by below 2 level of fields and push above prepared level 1)*
> >
> > > 3. **mainCategory** *(group by below 1 level of field and push above prepared level 2)*
> > >
> > > > 4. **group** *(project and show prepared level 3)*

Lets look step by step,

- your `$match` condition

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  { $match: { group: "Teknik" } },
```

- `$group` by with only 3 main fields, don't add `subSubCategory`
- this group prepare `subSubCategory` array

```
  {
    $group: {
      _id: {
        group: "$group",
        mainCategory: "$mainCategory",
        subCategory: "$subCategory"
      },
      subSubCategory: {
        $push: { name: "$subSubCategory" }
      }
    }
  },
```

- in above `$group` there will be chance of duplicate `subSubCategory` so this will remove duplicate, if you don't want to remove then you can skip this part

```
  {
    $addFields: {
      subSubCategory: { $setUnion: ["$subSubCategory", [] ] }
    }
  },
```

- now `$group` by only 2 main fields
- this will prepares `subCategory` array, push `name` and `subSubCategory` array that we have prepared in above group

```
  {
    $group: {
      _id: {
        group: "$_id.group",
        mainCategory: "$_id.mainCategory"
      },
      subCategory: {
        $push: {
          name: "$_id.subCategory",
          subSubCategory: "$subSubCategory"
        }
      }
    }
  },
```

- `$group` by main `group` field
- this will prepare `mainCategory` array, push `name` and `subCategory` array that we have prepared in above group

```
  {
    $group: {
      _id: "$_id.group",
      mainCategory: {
        $push: {
          name: "$_id.mainCategory",
          subCategory: "$subCategory"
        }
      }
    }
  },
```

- `$project` to remove `_id` and show `group` and `mainCategory` fields

```
  {
    $project: {
      _id: 0,
      group: "$_id",
      mainCategory: 1
    }
  }
])
```

Playground: https://mongoplayground.net/p/Uw8HmhSKqzv

Comment: Thanky you very much! Works as intended with the data i provided. However, i noticed that I've missed to inlcude testdata that share the group but not the mainCategory. sorry about that. Ive updataded the mongoplayground with more accurate testdata and with your code. I would really appricate it if you could give me som pointers how to fix this.https://mongoplayground.net/p/C0-L-rGPfwy

Comment: i can see subSubCategory is empty string in many documents, what is your expectation for that? and i can see that single point, let me know if i am missing.

Comment: The empty string is there because it feels simpler to have an empty value instead of checking if the element exists or not every time. Some products have subSub and some don't. Sorry, I dont understand your last sentence?

Comment: I'm expecting the group name "teknik" only once, and then should mainCategory be an array with all the mainCategories (Mobil, Spel & Gaming, Ljud & Bild) in them. I do not want to remove main object when the subSub is empty as in above.

Comment: i have updated answer you can check, the problem was in last group, need to group by only `group` field, let me know if is there any problem,